# How to get the column-names from DBD::CSV?

Tags: csv, perl, dbi

How can I get the `column-names` from the table? This did not work:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use DBI;

my $options  = { RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 0, f_ext => ".csv/r" };
my $dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:CSV:", undef, undef, $options ) or die $DBI::errstr;

my $table = 'test';
$dbh->do( "CREATE TEMP TABLE $table ( id INT, size INT )" );
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "INSERT INTO $table ( id, size ) VALUES( ?, ? )" );
$sth->execute( 1, 235 );
$sth->execute( 2, 42 );

use Data::Dumper;
say Dumper $dbh->{csv_tables}{$table}{col_names};

$dbh->{csv_tables}{$table} = { skip_first_row => 0 };
$sth = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $table" );
$sth->execute;
my @first_row = $sth->fetchrow_array;
say "@first_row\n";

$sth = $dbh->column_info( '', '', $table, '' );
my $ref = $sth->fetchall_arrayref;
say "@$_" for @$ref;
```

Error:

```
$VAR1 = undef;

1 235

Can't call method "fetchall_arrayref" on an undefined value at ./so.pl line 25.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `column_info` method is supposed to be implemented by the driver, and you get `undef` if it has not been.

Instead I'd look at `$sth->{NAME}` after you executed the first query.

Incidentally `DBD::CSV` is a fun toy, but if you need a lightweight throwaway database I strongly recommend using `DBD::SQLite` instead.  And if you just need to handle CSV data, there are several decent modules out there that give you raw access.  Between those two, there are very few use cases left where `DBD::CSV` makes much sense.